# Prevent a column from being compared

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with three columns: a, b and c. The above code works for column a, b and c. The third column gives undefined value. I want to prevent this column from comparing, i.e. if I enter values in column a and b and leave column c as it is, the data should be saved. How to achieve this?

```js
function saving(id) {
  var store;

  $('#mt .tb tr td').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).find("input").val();

    if (value === '' || value == null || value == " ")
      store == "0";
    else
      store == "1";
  });

  if (store = "0") {
    alert("empty rows cannot be saved")

    return false;
  } else
    return true;

  alert("saving successful")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mt">
  <tr>
    <thead>
      <th>a</th>
      <th>b</th>
      <th>c</th>
    </thead>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <tbody class="tb">
      <td><input id="a"></td>
      <td><input id="b"></td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-pencil Addbtn"></i></td>
    </tbody>
  </tr>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="return saving()">
</table>
```

Comment: You cannot put `<thead>` or `<tbody>` inside of `<tr>`. `store == "0";` and `store == "1";` do not do anything. `if (store = "0")` is not a comparison. Also, this is not Java.

Comment: Additionally, the return value from an onclick of a submit input type is usually used to prevent submission of a form, and you don't appear to have a form.    Use = for assignment, and == for comparison, and perhaps true and false instead of "0" and "1".

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to the columns you don't want to compare

```
<td class='nocompare'>
```

and exclude those

```
$('#mt .tb tr td:not(.nocompare)').each
```

(or you could add `compare` to the ones you do want to compare to remove the double negative.

---

There were some other fundamental issues with the code:

- setting a value uses `=` not `==` (`store == 0`)
- comparing a value uses `==` (or `===`) not `=` (`if (store = 0)`)
- you had an alert *after* the last return which would never get hit
- by setting store = 1, your check only needs the last column to have a value and will pass if all of the ones before failed.

for the last issue, you can add up a count of all the passes and compare with how many there should be, eg:

```
var pass = 0;
$('#mt .tb tr td.check').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).find("input").val();
    if (value === '' || value == null || value == " ")
       ; // fail
    else
       pass++;
});

if (pass == $('#mt .tb tr td.check').length))
    // all passed
```

or you can go with a bit flag and AND it as below.

```js
function saving(id) {
  var store = 1;

  $('#mt .tb tr td.check').each(function() {
    var value = $(this).find("input").val();

    if (value === '' || value == null || value == " ")
      store = 0;
    else
      store = store & 1;
  });

  if (store == "0") {
    alert("empty rows cannot be saved")
    return false;
  } else {
    alert("saving successful")
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mt">
  <tr>
    <thead>
      <th>a</th>
      <th>b</th>
      <th>c</th>
    </thead>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <tbody class="tb">
      <td class='check'><input id="a"></td>
      <td class='check'><input id="b"></td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-pencil Addbtn"></i></td>
    </tbody>
  </tr>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="return saving()">
</table>
```